# Output data from the date of activation of more than one year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table clients:

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
tariff VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL NULL,
validity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
phoneNumber VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=UTF8;

INSERT INTO clients (id,tariff,validity,phoneNumber) VALUES    (1,"tariff1","10-02-2015","380938474271");
INSERT INTO clients (id,tariff,validity,phoneNumber) VALUES (2,"tariff1","10-02-2016","380938474272");
INSERT INTO clients (id,tariff,validity,phoneNumber) VALUES (3,"tariff2","12-01-2017","380938474273");
INSERT INTO clients (id,tariff,validity,phoneNumber) VALUES (4,"tariff3","10-01-2017","380938474274");
INSERT INTO clients (id,tariff,validity,phoneNumber) VALUES (5,"tariff3","11-02-2017","380938474275");
```

My field validity is a date of activation. 
How can I select from this table field with date of activation  of more than one year ? Example, for this table it will clients with id 1 and 2.

Comment: Why store dates in a varchar column? Doesn't MySQL have any proper date data type?

Comment: Don't store dates as `varchar`, and don't use a funky format of `mm-dd-yyyy`, it will only cause you trouble later on.

Comment: ok . I''l use datetime format. 
I try it: SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE (activation_date >= NOW() AND activation_date <= NOW() + INTERVAL 365 DAY)

But it doesn't work

Comment: I don't see activation_date in your table  .. you mean validity?

Comment: I created it such activation_code format datetime

Comment: What do you mean by "date of activation of more than one year"? The date in ID 2 is only 5 months ago, less than a year.

Comment: Yes , it is wrong. 
I means dates such 2015-02-02 12:12:12 etc. 
I try it: SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE activation_date <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR; 

But it doesn't work

Comment: It should be `-`, not `+`.

Comment: If you wrote it wrong in the question, please edit it to say what you really mean. And put your attempted code in the question, not comments.

Comment: Yes, It should be - . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should convert to a proper date you varchar value and the check if is < of now sub 1year

```
select * from clients
where str_to_date(validity , '%d-%m-%Y') < date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
```

Comment: He said it should select id 1 and 2. This will only select id 1. It's not clear what his question is.

Comment: @Barmar   .. Now()  - 1 Year  should return rows  1 and  2

Comment: row 2 is only 5 months ago, your query returns rows more than 1 year ago.